# How to find the roots of this polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The polynomial: $8x^4-8x^2+1=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

I can simplify with $u=x^{2}$ to $8u^2-8u+{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}=0$  **Mistake** $\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$

apply the quadratic formula: $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ 
$$\frac{-(-8)\pm\sqrt{(-8)^2-4(8)\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} } {2a}$$

reduces to: $u=1\pm \frac{\sqrt{64-16\sqrt{3}}}{2}$

That is what I have done.  then I just take the square root of each value of u, and that will give me all 4 values?

I checked my result with [wolfalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%288x%5E4-8x%5E2%2b1=sqrt%283%29/2,x%29). I don't understand why when it say completing the square did it add $1/4$ and not $\left(\frac{-b}{2}\right)$?

Comment: There is a 1 in your first equation that is missing in your second equation.

Comment: Also, your third line doesn't follow from either the second or the first. Looks like you have applied the quadratic formula incorrectly.

Comment: @GerryMyerson where did I make the mistake?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I get it $1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ doesn't equal $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: You could post and accept your answer, then, so we have one and the question doesn't keep coming up.

Comment: @RossMillikan have to wait 2 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Gerry Myerson pointed out, I made a mistake.

$8u^2-8u+\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)=0$

the quadratic eq works here.